# How to count the number of values for each index in Python->Pandas->DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next DataFrame:

```
a = [{'x1':'a, b, c, d, e, f'}, {'x1':'a, b, c'}, {'x1':'a'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
```

I need to create the new column -> len_x1 in DataFrame and insert into it the amount of values in each cell.

I need the next result:

[image]

I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible count separator and add `1` use:

```
df['x1_len'] = df['x1'].str.count(',') + 1
print (df)
                 x1  x1_len
0  a, b, c, d, e, f       6
1           a, b, c       3
2                 a       1
```

Or count words:

```
df['x1_len'] = df['x1'].str.count('\w+')
```

Comment: thanks for help, in my situation I need str.count(',') + 1, because sometimes I have the next values -> 'a.r, a, b, b.r' ect.